# Поиск внутри collection (backbone.js)

Tags: underscore.js, javascript, backbone.js

Допустим, есть модель `User` с атрибутами `id` и `name`. Модель находиться в коллекции `UserList`.

Я хочу быстро получить модель из коллекции, у которой имя равно `"Jhony"` или вместо нее `null`, если таковой модели нет. Как мне это сделать?

Как выход, можно, конечно, поискать через `underscore` функции `map`, `detect`, `select`. Но это кажется очень нагроможденным.

Comment: <pre>
var Jhony = UserList.filter(function(user) {
  return user.get("name") === Jhony;
});
</pre>
если верить [Backbone Collection](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods)

Comment: filter это алис select

Еще возможно что в Jhony будет [].

Comment: Ну да, но "быстрее" способа я не знаю=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно получать *быстро*, а моделей — *много* (т.е. `O(n)` не устраивает), но, при этом, значения полей небольшие и памятью можно пожертвовать — можно построить индексы.

Например, сделав вспомогательный класс как-то так:

```
class IndexedCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  index_by: []
  initialize: ->
    @_indexes = {by_key: {}, by_id: {}}
    super

  _onModelEvent: (ev, model, collection, options) ->
    retval = super(ev, model, collection, options)
    id = model.id
    for k in @index_by
      v = model.get(k)
      @_indexes.by_key[k] ?= {}
      @_indexes.by_key[k][v] ?= []
      @_indexes.by_id[k] ?= {}

      prev = @_indexes.by_id[k][id]
      if prev? and prev != v
        @_indexes.by_key[k][prev] = _.without @_indexes.by_key[k][prev], id
      @_indexes.by_id[k][id] = v

      switch ev
        when "add", "change" then
            @_indexes.by_key[k][v] = _.union @_indexes.by_key[k][v], [id]
        when "remove" then
            @_indexes.by_key[k][v] = _.without @_indexes.by_key[k][v], id
    retval

getByIndex:(key, value) ->
  for id in @_indexes.by_key[key]?[value] ? []
    @.get(id)
```

Код — импровизация, набросок и прототип, не шибко оптимизированный и тестированный.

И, да, извините за CoffeeScript, надеюсь разница значения не имеет — на JS писать как-то лень.

Comment: Не извиняю за CoffeScript! Я как увидел код, сразу понял, что я упустил что-то и зря ранее не обращал на CoffeScript внимания. Огромное спасибо за идею с индексами и за новый язык. Я теперь понимаю вашу лень писать на js.

Comment: кстати, ``CoffeeScript`` и ``BackBone.js`` творения одного и того же программиста=)

Comment: круто! индекс на клиенте!

Answer (score 3):

Видимо нет более простого способа, в итоге я сделал себе метод у коллекции, что бы не было так громоздко, может кому поможет:

```
getByAttr: function(attr, value){
    return this.detect( function(model){
       return model.get(attr) == value; 
    });
},
```